# Get one resulting list with the max or min by index in a nested list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Lets say I have this structure

```
[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[8,9],[7,7]]]
```

I want to iterate the list and have this result:

```
[[3,2],[8,7]]
```

This is would be reducing the list list of arrays in the first level `[[1,2],[3,4]]` to one single array where the maximum selected for the first element and the minimum is found for the second.

I have already done it manually, just iterating the groups, iterating again, storing the first value and seeing if the next is bigger or smaller, I store it in a list and create another list.

I would like to find a more elegant method with list comprehensions and so on, I'm pretty sure I can use zip here to group the values in the same group but I haven't been successful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`, and by unpacking the result into individual values it is pretty easy to do what you are looking for, e.g.:

```
>>> x = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[8,9],[7,7]]]
>>> [[max(a), min(b)] for k in x for a, b in [zip(*k)]]
[[3, 2], [8, 7]]
```

An alternative way without unpacking is to have a cycling function iterable (`max, min, max, min, ...`) and use nested list comprehensions, e.g.:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> maxmin = it.cycle([max, min])
>>> [[next(maxmin)(a) for a in zip(*k)] for k in x]
[[3, 2], [8, 7]]
```

Or index into a list of functions:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> maxmin = [max, min]
>>> [[maxmin[i](a) for i, a in enumerate(zip(*k))] for k in x]
[[3, 2], [8, 7]]
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to use zip, it was just what I though might help. I'll see how this applies, the lists are actually of four elements.

Comment: The comment was for the previous answer before the edit, I'll check this one.

Comment: What do you mean 4 elements, can you give a more complete example? This doesn't care how many `pairs` you have or how many `groups of pairs` you have but will not work if you have more than `pairs` though it is easy to extend - `a, b, c, d`

Comment: This seems to work exactly as I need, disregard the first comment, I'm just giving it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This will work without zip:

```
mylist = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[8,9],[7,7]]]
[[max(y[0] for y in x), min(y[1] for y in x)] for x in mylist]
```

The main disadvantage of this is that it looks through each sub-list twice, once to find the maximum (of the first items) and once to find the minimum (of the second items).

Comment: Oh nice, this seems pretty much what I need, the only problem is that I have four, so I would have to iterate four times each... but I don;t think it's that performance dependent. I'll give it a go.